# Mongoose how to use positional operator to pull from double nested array with specific condition, and return new result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(1),
  title: string,
  answers: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId(2),
      text: string,
      upVotes: [
        {
           _id: ObjectId(3),
           userId: ObjectId(4)
        }
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

What I want is pull vote of a specific user from answer upvotes, and return the new update result.
For example, find a question with id 1, and get its specific answer with id 2, then from that answer pull my vote using userId inside upvotes.
I want to do it with a single `findOneAndUpdate` query

Comment: I am seeing uses of two positional operators here. Have you tried it?

Comment: btw MongoDB doesn't allow to use of two `$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even use single [**`$`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional with the [**`$pull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator to update the nested array

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": ObjectId(1), "answers._id": ObjectId(2) },
  { "$pull": { "answers.$.upVotes": { "userId": ObjectId(4) }}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood that you want to do a search in the specific array

```
db.collection.update(

    { 
         "_id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",  // id field
            "answers.upVotes._id":"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011" //id  array
    } 
    ),{
     "$set":{"answers.$.upVotes": {userId :"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"}}},//edit

//use "addToSet" for add
```